# Techniques to implement a notification service

Tags: android, architecture, service, notifications

I have a main activity where the user can enable/disable notifications, set the notification interval, and set the base time the notification interval will use. Notifications will typically trigger about 2 hours from each other.  After a certain time, an accumulator will reach a maximum value and notifications will no longer be needed.

What is the standard way of implementing such a notification scheme?  I tried using a handler inside of a service using `postAtTime`, but it seems that there are a lot of conditions that can cause it to never run.  I looked at a timer inside of the service, but putting the phone in standby will stop any timers, plus it just seems like a bad idea.

The only other option I came across I have yet to explore, but it involves using an `AlarmManager` and a `BroadcastReceiver`.  Should I just ditch the service and schedule a repeating alarm instead?  I need to be able to disable all remaining alarms once my accumulator has reached max value.

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I will always have a finite number of notifications and I can calculate the elapsed time in advance, it seems the combination of `AlarmManager` and a `BroadcastReceiver` work pretty well.  Here is how I implemented this:

I first created a `BroadcastReceiver`

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //Get handle to system notification manager
        NotificationManager mNM = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        //Get message from intent
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        CharSequence text = bundle.getString("notification_message");

        // Set the icon, scrolling text and timestamp
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.notification_icon, text, System.currentTimeMillis());

        // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this notification
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);

        // Set the info for the views that show in the notification panel.
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, context.getText(R.string.app_name),text, contentIntent);

        // Set Flags
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // Send the notification.
        mNM.notify(R.string.notification, notification);

    }

}
```

I then created a class that used a `AlarmManager` to create/cancel alarms that send a message to the `BroadcastReceiver`

```
public class NotificationSender {

    private AlarmManager mAlarmManager;
    private Context mContext;
    private Intent mIntent;

    public NotificationSender(Context context){

        this.mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        this.mIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationReceiver.class);
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public void setAlarm(Long etaMillis, int accumulator){

        //Create intent to send to Receiver
        this.mIntent.putExtra("notification_message","Message");

        //Use accumulator as requestCode so we can cancel later
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.mContext, accumulator, this.mIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        //Set Alarm
        mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, etaMillis, sender);

    }

    public void cancelAlarms(){

        //requestCode (accumulator) will always be a multiple of 10 and less than 100
        for (int x = 10; x <= 100; x += 10){
            PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.mContext, x, this.mIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            mAlarmManager.cancel(operation);
        }

    }

    public void createAlarms(PreferenceHelper prefs){

        //Calculate time notifications are due and set an alarm for each one
        //PreferenceHelper is a class to help pull values from shared preferences
        Date currentTime = new Date();

        for (int i = prefs.getNotificationInterval(); i <= 100; i += prefs.getNotificationInterval()) {

            if (i > prefs.getAccumulator()) {

                this.setAlarm(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + calculateETA(i, prefs).getTime() - currentTime.getTime(), i);

            }

        }

    }

    public void refreshAlarms(PreferenceHelper prefs){

        this.cancelAlarms();
        if (prefs.isNotificationsEnabled()) this.createAlarms(prefs);

    }

}
```

The important part is to use the accumulator as the `requestCode` so we can cancel all of our alarms later.

Finally I used the `NotificationSender` class in my activity by calling `refreshAlarms()` in `onCreate()` and whenever the user modifies preferences that are relevant to scheduling notifications.  Rebooting the phone will clear all alarms so the app must be restarted before notifications will begin.  If the system happens to kills the process, the alarms will still trigger at the appropriate time.

Comment: will it still run even if I killed the application?

Answer (score 0):

What if you start a service that spawns a thread like this:

```
thread t = new thread(new Runnable(){
    public void Run(){
       boolean notified = false;
       while( !notified ){
          if( notify_time - time > 1000 ){
              Thread.sleep(999);
          else if( notify_time - time <= 0 ){
              // START NOTIFICATION ACTIVITY
              notified = true;
          }
       }
    }
}

t.start();
```

I have not done anything like this personally, so I am not sure what service can do to notify the user or start an activity, but it does have the full panoply of options available to an activity, so yeah.

Oh but it just occured to me you'll need to use a handler for that because of the multithreaded aspect here.